# Trouble setting up IKEv2/IPsec on 18.04 - Unable to locate package strongswan-ikev2

Tags: networking, vpn, 18.04

I'm running 18.04 and trying to setup a IKEv2/IPsec VPN. I'm following directions from the VPN provider [NordVPN IKEv2/IPsec setup instructions for Linux](https://nordvpn.com/tutorials/linux/ikev2ipsec/)  I can't install all the required dependencies.

### After running:

```
sudo apt install strongswan strongswan-plugin-eap-mschapv2 strongswan-ikev2 libstrongswan-standard-plugins
```

### The following errors are received:

```
E: Unable to locate package strongswan-plugin-eap-mschapv2
E: Unable to locate package strongswan-ikev2
```

Any advice on installing these packages?

Answer (score 8):

`strongswan-ikev2` was a transitional package that has been removed with 18.04.  It caused `strongswan-charon` to get installed, which is (and was) also the case if you just installed the `strongswan` metapackage.  The latter also installs the `strongswan-starter` package that provides configuration via the classic `ipsec.conf` backend and `ipsec` control interface, which the tutorial currently seems to be referring to.

To use the more modern [vici](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Vici)/[swanctl](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Swanctl) configuration backend and control interface you may install the `strongswan-swanctl` package, or the `charon-systemd` package that pulls that in too and provides a `systemd` integrated IKE daemon (a separate version of strongSwan's `charon` daemon) .

The individual plugin packages were removed already with 17.10 and since 16.04 they were actually just aliases for `libcharon/libstrongswan-extra-plugins`. So if you need additional EAP authentication plugins install the `libcharon-extra-plugins` package.

Comment: I am using UBUNTU 20 LTS and need to install  VPN package... The best option is `strongswan-swanctl` or `charon-systemd`?