# How to connect to a VPN site using console only?

Tags: command-line, vpn, ipsec

What I've found so far, there are tutorials to use Network Manager to connect to VPN.

Is it possible to create a VPN connection only from the console (Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, either Ubuntu 16.x)?

Available assets:

- public IP address of the VPN site, ikev2
- user name
- password
- private shared key (PSK)

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: First, you need to install the `strongswan` package on your Linux system.

Open `terminal` and paste the following line:

```
sudo apt -y install strongswan-plugin-eap-mschapv2 libcharon-extra-plugins libstrongswan-extra-plugins
```

Step 2: Edit your config by running the command:

```
sudo nano /etc/ipsec.conf
```

> `conn` is the name of the connection, it can be any as you like
>   `eap_identity` is your login that can be found in the Customer Area of your VPN. 
>   `right` is your server address. 
>   In `auto` write `add`.

Login and server address are the credentials that you have got from the Customer Area of your VPN. Use Tab key to follow the indentation of the parameters.

When you finish, your config will look similar to this:

```
 conn example
                keyexchange=ike
                dpdaction=clear
                dpddelay=300s
                eap_identity=login
                leftauth=eap-mschapv2
                left=%defaultroute
                leftsourceip=%config
                right=example.com
                rightauth=pubkey
                rightsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
                rightid=%any
                type=tunnel
                auto=add
```

To save the file you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>   <kbd>X</kbd>  key combination, then  <kbd>Y</kbd>  key and then  <kbd>Enter</kbd> .
Now you are back to the command line.

Step 3: Disable the `constraints` plugin.

```
sudo nano /etc/strongswan.d/charon/constraints.conf
```

Change `load = yes` to `load = no`
To save the file you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>   <kbd>X</kbd>  key combination, then  <kbd>Y</kbd>  key and then  <kbd>Enter</kbd> .

Step 4: Write your credentials into `/etc/ipsec.secrets`

```
sudo nano /etc/ipsec.secrets
```

`login: password`

You need to replace them with your login and password that you obtained from the Customer Area of your VPN.

Step 5: Execute the following two commands so `StrongSwan` can verify VPN's certificate:

```
sudo rmdir /etc/ipsec.d/cacerts
sudo ln -s /etc/ssl/certs /etc/ipsec.d/cacerts
```

Step 6: Restart `strongswan` daemon:

```
sudo ipsec restart
```

Step 7: To start the connection:

```
sudo ipsec up example
```

`example` is the name of the VPN connection that you used in Step 2.

To disconnect, type:

```
sudo ipsec down example
```

Step 8: To be sure if you are successfully connected please visit http://ipinfo.io/ip in your web browser and check your IP address at the top of the page.

You can also check the status of your connection by typing:
sudo ipsec status

Comment: thank you very much @Tejas Lotlikar!
though it seems that this tutorial would rather work in Ubuntu 16.04! 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029907/trouble-setting-up-ikev2-ipsec-on-18-04-unable-to-locate-package-strongswan-ik/1030024

Comment: You had forgotten to mention the version of Ubuntu which you were using.

Comment: never mind! I've tested your great and very helpful instruction with Ubuntu 16.04 with the following outcomes:

* ```/etc/ipsec.d/``` did not exist; creating it worked for me
* you have not mentioned that for ```ipsec up``` one package more is needed, ```strongswan-starter```. Maybe it's worth adding to the instruction.

Comment: However on the connection attempt there is the following error:
```initiating IKE_SA example[2] to <VPN_ENDPOINT>
generating IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(HASH_ALG) ]
sending packet: from <CLIENT_ENDPOINT>[500] to <VPN_ENDPOINT>[500] (1500 bytes)
received packet: from <VPN_ENDPOINT>[500] to <CLIENT_ENDPOINT>[500] (36 bytes)
parsed IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ N(NO_PROP) ]
received NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN notify error
establishing connection 'example' failed```

- Is it possible to get more debugging information? Would you say this is an error on the server side?

Comment: also another question; where does PSK go to in the suggested setup?

Comment: @J.Doe in Step 4 we enter the credentials i.e. login is eap_identity and password is the PSK

Comment: Contents of my ipsec.secrets  is :  'yourloginname' : EAP 'yourpasswd'

Comment: @TejasLotlikar if password is the PSK, where does the password go to?

Answer (score 0):

If I follow instructions provided by @Tejas Lotlikar there is some mismatch with the hanshake.

[Another tutorial](https://howto.lintel.in/configure-ipsecl2tp-vpn-clients-linux-cli/) works both for Ubuntu 16 and 18 and everything is fine regarding opening the IPSEC link to remote server, but then the PPP0 interface can't be created without recognizable error.

This issue has been known so far for a buggy kernel; for I've got a 4.15 from AWS. I'll try to change the kernel to the latest official 4.15.